# NativeScript native bridgle plugin for Android custom library integration

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to build a bridge plugin from a custom library. I am having issues integrating the library.

Here is where I have:

```
//index.js

var application = require("application");
var context = application.android.context;

module.exports = {

   showScanner: function() {

var MRZ = new com.example.mrz_scanner_natives_plugin.ScannerActivity();
    MRZ.startScanner

}

//include.gradle

android {
    productFlavors{
        "mrz-plugin"{
            dimension "mrz-plugin"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'mrzscannerlib', ext: 'aar')
}

//Java Activity 

import com.scansolutions.mrzscannerlib.MRZScannerListener;

public class ScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements MRZScannerListener {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);

    }

  private void startScanner(){
        mrzScanner.setMaxThreads(2);
        mrzScanner = (MRZScanner) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.scannerFragment);

    }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find
>   class "com.scansolutions.mrzscannerlib.MRZScannerListener"

Comment: Have you included the AAR you built in the platforms folder?

Comment: Yes, i've added it in platforms/android/libs

Comment: Try to place it in `android` directory itself not libs, do a clean build of your demo app.

Comment: did exactly what you told me but im getting the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateReleaseRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find :mrzscannerlib:.
     Required by:
         project :

Comment: Do you have the Github repo?

Comment: Hi @Manoj, here's the github repository: https://github.com/vasep/MrzPlugin.
I've added the android plugin (mrzscannernativeSplugin), the bridge (mrz-plugin), and the TestApp(TestMRZANSAPP).
I'd be very grateful if you could help me out.

Comment: I don't seem have access to the repo, is it private?